# header("Location:/"); redirect works on localhost, but not on remote server

Tags: php, apache, localhost

```
if (condition)
{
#lol. Some code here
}
else
{       
header("Location:/");//i'm trying to redirect to the root
}
```

Redirect works perfectly on localhost, but not on remote server.
May be it's all better to use `$_SERVER`?
This redirect wouldn't work even if i choose file in the same directory as file with redirect.
Hope you help me :)

Comment: I think you need a space: `header("Location: /")` Although, I imagine you're better substituting in an actual URL. Somewhere I seem to remember reading it's a flaw or a bug that `header("Location: mypage.php")` works at all.

Comment: To redirect to the server root, you could use header('location:'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);

Comment: @JaredFarrish It doesn't work ,sorry.

Comment: If I had thought it was the answer to the "problem" of using a `/` in a location header, I would have posted it as the answer. The easy way to fix this is to abandon that technique and *use a real path*.

Comment: I got it your code and my code work perfect. Something is wrong with my if..else construction. Redirect doesn't work there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

> HTTP/1.1 requires an absolute URI as argument to » Location: including the scheme, hostname and absolute path, but some clients accept relative URIs. You can usually use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`, `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` and `dirname()` to make an absolute URI from a relative one yourself:

```
<?php
/* Redirect to a different page in the current directory that was requested */
$host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$uri   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
$extra = 'mypage.php';
header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra");
exit;
?>
```