# PHP headers not working on server but works on local server?

Tags: php

```
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=filename.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
```

On my local system above code work properly but on server its not work.

Comment: please define "not working" :)

Comment: Define 'not working'?

Comment: What append exactly? An error?

Comment: maybe you should change content type? try this header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');

Comment: Check this [link][1] if it provides any clue related to your question


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072042/headerlocation-redirect-works-on-localhost-but-not-on-remote-server

Answer (score 0):

I don't know yet if it will help you, but if you wan't, you can generalize `octet-stream` output for some extension, directly in VirtualHost config.

For that, use `AddType application/octet-stream .xlsx .xls`

And all url to *Excel* files would be downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

write ob_clean() just before the last line below , i was having same problem got resolved by this

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="temlik.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
ob_clean();
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```