# PHP Header Location is not working in localhost xampp?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, xampp

i am trying to redirect the page using header location in xampp but it is not working and redirecting to localhost/dashboard

i used the following code for simple redirecting in localhost , i placed my site in htdocs/test/   and files in that are index.html and index.php,  the index.php code is as follows

```
<?php 
      header("Location:/index.html");
 ?>
```

when i am trying to access http://localhost/test/index.php it is not going to localhost/test/index.html 
but it is redirecting to http://localhost/dashboard/

Comment: Do you have any space before the <?php tag ?

Comment: no i do't have any space

Comment: Check this link it my help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072042/headerlocation-redirect-works-on-localhost-but-not-on-remote-server

Comment: no it is not working same problem

Comment: @Amit Ray  it is for live server but my problem is with localhost

Comment: Add an exit; command after header location and check so that no more codes get executed after redirection.

Comment: no still it is showing same thing

Answer (score 2):

Check in your php.ini file that output_buffering=On; then use this code to redirect to index.html

```html
<?php 
ob_start();
     if (headers_sent()) {
   
    die("Redirect failed.");
}
else{
    exit(header("Location: index.html"));
}
?>
```

You can get details of ob_start from here http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

Comment: same problem even using it is there any problem with htaccess file

Comment: Didi you check your php.ini file for output_buffering. Whether it is on or Off? If it is off then ob_start() wont work. Also did you replace /index.html to index.html?

Comment: yes i checked php.ini file output buffering is ON , i just copied your code and placed and checked no work same problem

Comment: Try this : Change the line exit(header("Location: index.html")); to exit(header("Location: index.html", true, 301)); Rename temporarily your htaccess file and restart your server. Check if it redirects properly now.

Answer (score 0):

i know your problem and this should fix it.

in your index.php

```
<?php 
header('Location: ./index.html');


?>
```

where `./` represents current directory

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<?php
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"javascript\">
        window.location.replace(\"index.html\");
      </script>";

?>
```

Comment: When answering a question, please provide some background. _why_ is this the answer? _why_ does this work?